# How can i fix the problem with the MKMapView in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I am building a map-based app and I can't stretch my MKMapView to the borders though I already created constrains.

When I run my app on a simulator my map is smaller than should be.

Comment: maybe add more information about how you've created the constraints and where? code examples or interface builder screenshots would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually because you have created those constraints to the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` of the parent view. You need to ignore the safeAreaLayoutGuide while providing the constraint. Select the superview's top, leading, bottom and trailing anchors instead of the superview's safeAreaLayoutGuide's anchors.